# C programming constantly updating variable in for loop

Tags: c

I am learning to code and I face an issue regarding undeclared variables in the for loop. Any feedback or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

I have provided a T and an R value as shown in the code below. However, by trying to add a for loop, the variable becomes undeclared. I would like to compare the value of T0 T1 T2 to T7 using a for loop with the Ti variable. How do I include the Ti variable so that the i constantly change according to the for loop?

```
int T0=0, T1=1, T2=1, T3=0, T4=0, T5=1, T6=1, T7=0;

int R0=0, R1=0, R2=1, R3=0, R4=1, R5=1, R6=0, R7=0;

int j=0;
int r;

for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
{
    if (Ti==1)
    {
        r = Ri;
        j++;
    }
    else
        i++;

   printf("The output for r is %d", r);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a perfect candidate for an array.

Comment: You cannot dynamically change a variable's name. Try using an array.

Comment: Don't tag a question about C with the C++ tag unless you're particularly fond of downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to use an array instead of these variables like `T1`, `T2`, ..., etc. As `T0`, `T1` are considered as variables and as per rule for the identifiers declaration this is wrong way. The compiler is using `Ti` as a variable and showing error, that it is undeclared.

Additionally, there will be a path through your loop that does not write into `r`, if all elements of `T[]` are not equal to 1, given that you change it somewhen. Better initialize `r`.

I have attached a working code below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int T[8] = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 };
    int R[8] = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 };
    int j = 0;
    int r = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (T[i] == 1) {
            r = R[i];
            j++;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }

        printf("The output for r is %d\n", r);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your idea for solving the problem as a beginner is truly appreciable. Keep it up.